# VB.NET XML Parser - Find elements with specific attribute & value

Tags: xml, vb.net, parsing, xhtml

HI,

I am using VB.NET to read an XHTML file. I need my program to find every element within the XML structure which has the "class" attribute set to a specific value.

IE: I need an array (or similar list) of all elements from the document which contain class="mytag".

There is a list of several values I need to detect, all of which start with the same word 'mytag' followed by another word - so using a "contains" function seems sensible here.

Any suggestions of ways I can parse out these attributes would be appreciated.
Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp) expression with the [`SelectNodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectnodes.aspx) function of an [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) object:

```
//*[@class="mytag"]
```

This expression will select any XHTML element whose `class` attribute's value is equal to `"mytag"`.

If you want to find all elements whose `class` attribute contains a particular string, the XPath function `contains` will help you:

```
//*[contains(@class,"mytag")]
```

The `SelectNodes` function returns a list of XML nodes from the `XmlDocument` corresponding on the XPath expression passed to it as a parameter. Based on your description, it's exactly what you need.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks.
I am however having trouble with my xml document being loaded. the xml reader is trying to validate the xml using the DTD. This means an extra trip to the W3C website on load - slowing processing times.
If, however, I set the XMLresolver of the reader to Nothing, parsing crashes because the document contains things like &nbsp; and &copy;

How can I load the xmldocument without this validation, but still allow the &nbsp and &copy etc?

Thanks.

Comment: @Jack Hayter: You should be able to look into the `XmlReader.Settings.ValidationFlags` property, which lets you pick and choose what validations, if any, are performed on the XML as it's read in. See this for more information about `ValidationFlags`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.validationflags.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with LINQ try XML literals,

Like this:

```
Dim nodes = From currentNode In XmlDoc...<your-node-name>

For Each node As XElement In nodes

Console.Writeline(node.Attribute("attr-name").Value())

Next
```