# Program a webpage that returns Lat and Long from Google Map when an address is entered?

Tags: api, google-maps

I've looked at

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Locations

But it doesn't show how Google Map would return Lat and Long when an Address is entered.

Comment: It seems like the answer given from normalocity is the one you are seeking.Please accept it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the "geocoding" and "reverse geocoding" sections

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding

A sample page that does what you're describing:

http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/singlegeocode.html

Comment: thank you normalocity! The server would respond my request with an XML file, and the Lat/Long information is nested in a tag, I'm not sure how to extract that information...

Comment: The way you get the data out of the XML depends on other technologies in your website (for example, what language your site is written in, such as PHP, Ruby, Java, etc.). Look for what's called an "XML parser", and that should get you in the direction you need to go.

Comment: I'm coding my site in ASP (with VB.NET). Would I search for VB.NET XML parser?

Comment: Sure. Some resources: (1) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/parsefilecode.aspx (2) http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/shehperu/SimpleXMLParser11152005073044AM/SimpleXMLParser.aspx (3) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471307/vb-net-xml-parser-find-elements-with-specific-attribute-value